# Spring Security @PreAuthorize for validation of controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following method in my Controller.

```
    @GetMapping("/update/{idpost}")
    public String showUpdateForm(
            @PathVariable int idpost, 
            @ModelAttribute("post") Post post,
            @ModelAttribute("user") User user,
            Model model) {

        post = postService.findById(idpost);
        model.addAttribute("post", post);
        return "_updateForm";
    }
```

It's showing form for updating exist post.

I want to **limit access to the user who made this post only**. so that random user won't be able to access.

so I tried this.. aiming to correspond, current user's email(authentication.name) with post's owner's email. but no luck.

```
    @PreAuthorize("#post.user.email == authentication.name")
    @GetMapping("/update/{idpost}")
    public String showUpdateForm(
            @PathVariable int idpost, 
            @ModelAttribute("post") Post post,
            @ModelAttribute("user") User user,
            Model model) {

        post = postService.findById(idpost);
        model.addAttribute("post", post);
        return "_updateForm";
    }
```

It turned out that, **post** argument has a null value. which is obvious as it is defined ***in*** the method. (or way I used it completely wrong.)

Would you get what I am doing? How can I use @PreAuthorize for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem solved using RequestParam.

```
    @PreAuthorize("#userid == #user.id")
    @GetMapping("/update/{idpost}")
    public String showUpdateForm(
            @PathVariable int idpost, 
            @ModelAttribute("post") Post post,
            @ModelAttribute("user") User user,
            @RequestParam("u") int userid,
            Model model) {

        post = postService.findById(idpost);
        model.addAttribute("post", post);
        return "_updateForm";
    }
```

request uri could be like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/...../update/31?u=83
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that `PostAuthorize` is what you want. Note: I haven't used this annotation myself, but that's what it hints at. If this is not sufficient for you, let me know and I can investigate a bit more and see if I can get you a sample.

PS. Don't forget to enable PostAuthorize `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`

```java
    @PostAuthorize("#returnObject.user.email == authentication.name")
    public Post getPost(int idpost) {
        return postService.findById(idpost);
    }

    @GetMapping("/update/{idpost}")
    public String showUpdateForm(
            @PathVariable int idpost, 
            @ModelAttribute("user") User user,
            Model model) {

        post = getPost(idpost);
        model.addAttribute("post", post);
        return "_updateForm";
    }
```